# Can you use a .swf file which runs in a browser as an android/ios application instead?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, apk

I have purchased full rights to a browser based collaborative whiteboard written in flash, but it is quite complicated. This is needed as part of my website which includes video/voice chat.

The current android application already integrates the video/voice chat and this is working well. However, is there a way to use the whiteboard application inside of my existing app? Can I simply load the source code/assets into Adobe air and export it as a .apk file?

Edit: To be a bit more clear, I have a whiteboard which runs in browsers, but I need this to run inside/as part of my android application.

The whiteboard is loaded as a .swf file, but all source code is available to me.

Regards

Comment: Is _"the current android application"_ also made with AS3? If yes, do you have the source code? That code could be compiled with whiteboard swf embedded as asset or class file. Usually an APK cannot later (after installing) start loading extra / external SWF files that have their own (un-authorized) code. It's a security issue. So just embed the SWF **before** compiling and modify your app's AS3 source code to load the SWF. If your app was made with Java, you cannot use SWF.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot use SWF if app was made in Java? It is possible.

Comment: @3vilguy In android? Webview with plugins has been deprecated for a long while now...

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, in Android. And not via webview. AIR does it (it's basically wrapper for .swf), so it's doable.

Comment: @3vilguy So you're saying embed an AIR app in an Android app? Is that possible?

Comment: @Aaron https://github.com/3vilguy/android-invoke-adobe-AIR

Comment: @3vilguy Cool, never seen that before. Maybe you should write an answer. :)

Comment: @Aaron AIR is running on separate Intent. I'm not sure how to communicate between Java and AS3 part yet :( I ended up doing communication via sockets (server in Java and connecting from as3) but it's not ideal. Was trying to figure out similar way to how ANE are working but couldn't get it to work :(